# What Date Source(DS) and Round Robin Archive(RRA) should I choose for displaying information about multiple website registrations per period?

Tags: rrdtool

What Date Source(DS) and Round Robin Archive(RRA) should I choose for displaying information about multiple website registrations per period?

I want have RRA with one measurement = 5min. period. The Y axis displaying total number (not average) of registrations during last 5 minutes. Also, I want graph with information about total number of registrations (Y axis) per day (X axis).

What DS type and RRA "algoritm" shoud I choose to implement this?

Comment: Can you please add little more information about your query. What you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [rrd-beginners](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrd-beginners.en.html) guide. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, this should create the DB with the correct DST:

```
rrdtool create file_name.rrd /
  --start N --step 300 /
  DS:registrations:COUNTER:600:U:U /
  RRA:MAX:0.5:1:288
```

And this should produce the wanted readout:

```
rrdtool graph file_name.png --start -86400 \
  --x-grid HOUR:1:HOUR:8:HOUR:2:0:%Hh \
  --vertical-label "num" \
  TEXTALIGN:center \
  DEF:num_regs=file_name.rrd:registrations:MAX \
  LINE:num_regs#1F77B4:"Number of registrations"
```

Let me know if it works :)